# How can I get JavaScript to execute inside a Bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a popover for each link to a user containing their avatar and option to follow/unfollow. The follow/unfollow functionality works but not in a popover?

```
$('body').popover({ selector: '[data-popover]', trigger: 'click hover', placement: 'top', delay: {show: 50, hide: 400}});

$('.follow-user .follow, .follow-user .unfollow').on('click', function(){
    var el = $(this);

    var actionType = el.hasClass('unfollow') ? 'unfollow' : 'follow';

    var data = {
        actionType: actionType,
        userId: el.attr("data-uid")
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{path('ajax_follow_user')}}',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert('Error. please try again later!');
            el.removeClass('following');
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            el.addClass('following');
        },
        success: function(r){
            alert("success");
            if(r.error != '') {
                alert(r.error);
                return false;
            }
            alert(actionType);
            if (actionType == 'follow')
            {
                el.text("Unfollow");
                el.stop().removeClass('follow').addClass('unfollow');
            }
            else if (actionType == 'unfollow')
            {
                el.text("Follow");
                el.stop().removeClass('unfollow').addClass('follow');
            }

            el.removeClass('following').text(r.label);
        }
    });
});
```

.

```
<a href="#"
       data-popover="true"
       data-html="true"
       data-content='
<img src="{{ asset(user.avatar) }}" alt="{{ user.username }}"
     width="80" height="80" style="float:left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0"/> 
<strong>{{ user.username }}</strong> <br />
<span class="follow-user"><a class="follow" data-uid="{{ user.id }}">Follow</a></span> 
<div style="clear:both"></div> <br />'>
        {{ user.username }}
    </a>
```

Comment: Can you show us where are you defining the listener for the follow and unfollow action? It might be just a delegation issue.

Comment: @amenadiel in the Head tag below the popover js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are created dinamically by the popover component of bootstrap, and you cannot assign listeners to them beforehand.

However, event bubbling lets you attach the listener to the parent element (or its parent, up to the document) in the form

```
$(document).on('click', '.follow-user .follow, .follow-user .unfollow', function(){
    var el = $(this);
    ...
});
```

that's event delegation.

Comment: Yes, but you're attaching it to the ```.follow``` and ```.unfollow``` classes. I'm attaching it to the document, and use the second parameter of the ```.on``` method to select the real targets.

Comment: Ok i'll try this. Where do I put the closing bracket for .on(?

Comment: just replace the first line. I just changed the first selector and added a parameter to the method. The rest of your function remains untouched.

Comment: This works but do you know why the text reverts back to Follow? I hover over a link and popover comes up saying Follow, I click Follow and JavaScript executes successfully changing the text to Unfollow but if I exit and re-enter the popover it reverts back to Follow.

Comment: The popover is destroyed on mouseout, and a new one is created upon reenter. If you need to persist the status you'll need to store it as a data property of the container <a>, and look for an event to detect the popover opening to set the proper status.